# convert MKPlaceMark addressDictionary string encoded

Tags: iphone, mkreversegeocoder

I working on a example to using MKReverseGeocoder to convert lat,long to address. But when i received data and try to get the result i received string from as below:

```
NSString *street = [geocoder.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Street"];
```

I received a address like this: **"Ng\U00f5 381 Nguy\U1ec5n Khang"**.

How can i convert it to unicode formatted string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

If you are getting the MKPlaceMark object back from the MKRevereseGeocoder delegate callback you can use the following to turn the placemark into a readable address:

```
NSLog(@"Address of placemark: %@", ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placemark.addressDictionary, NO));
```

You need to add the AddressBookUI framework to your project and

> ```
> #import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
> ```

as well.

I'm not sure that the response is unicode, but it looks like it does a reasonable job of representing all the data in the placemark.

Untested, but

```
NSLog(@"Address of placemark: %@", [CNPostalAddressFormatter stringFromPostalAddress:placeMark.postalAddress style:CNPostalAddressFormatterStyleMailingAddress]);
```

And the framework needed is 'Contacts' so get that included with:

```
@import Contacts;
```

should be the new way of doing things in iOS11.0+

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/Reference/reference.html  Apple recommendation: "You can format the contents of this dictionary to get a full address string as opposed to building the address yourself. To format the dictionary, use the ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary function as described in Address Book UI Functions Reference."

Comment: Since iOS 9.0 `ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary` is deprecated.

Comment: i need solution for ios 9+

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting the `MKPlaceMark` object back from the `MKRevereseGeocoder` delegate callback you can use the following to turn the placemark into a readable address:

```
NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: %@", [placemark addressDictionary]);
//all elements returned

//you can get some object like coutry ,code ;code country ...

NSLog(@"country ::::%@",[placemark country]);

NSLog(@"countrycode ::::%@",[placemark countryCode]);

NSLog(@"postalcode ::::%@",[placemark postalcode]);

NSLog(@"street::::%@",[placemark thoroughfare]);

 NSLog(@"streetinfo::::%@",[placemark administrativeArea]);

NSLog(@"streeteersub ::::%@",[placemark subAdministrativeArea]);
```